# Is there a way to read messages from Facebook Messenger from another Android App?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-messenger

Like in the title. I am working on an application that will warn users against phishing. I found a way to read incoming text messages. However, I would like to be able to check messages that come to messengers such as Messenger or WhatsApp. I don't expect a ready-made solution. Just hints on ways that will help me achieve my goal, because I aware that something like this may be difficult or impossible to implement.

Thanks in advance for all answers.

Comment: No Facebook has no API to read user messages